# Any alternatives to SQL REPLACE function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, replace

I have an SSRS report that passes a string of County values to a SQL script and adds several characters to the end of each County value(this is done for an SSRS reason).  The SQL script uses the REPLACE function to remove those extra characters and replace them with ''.  However, the REPLACE function can take a long time to run if dealing with a large dataset.

Does anyone know of any faster alternatives to REPLACE?

Thanks!

Comment: are the characters added to the end of the same length?  could you just substring(1,lengh(field)-XX) where XX is the length of characters added? or does it vary?  have 2 fields in the report, 1 with unaltered value 1 with altered value and no replacement needed...  In other words, are you causing the problem you're trying to solve and can we fix the root cause instead of the symptom?

Comment: Can't use 2 fields and concat its on the report?

Comment: Yes, the characters added to the end are of the same length.  I'll try the substring.  Thx.

Comment: Even for me running query with Replace function is very slow, my query is below, can anyone help me please,

SELECT dbo.Orders.OrigID FROM dbo.Orders INNER JOIN dbo.OrderedReports ON dbo.Orders.OrigID = dbo.OrderedReports.OrderID WHERE (REPLACE(Orders.Email,'^^','''') = 'Khengtjinyap@gmail.com')